# Why is my imageview's 'trailing to safe area' constraint doesn't cover entire width. (Images attached)

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, interface-builder

I designed the screen for iphone SE and fixed all the constraints but when i switched to iPhone 8 view the imageview didn't strecth to safe area. I have attached the images with constraints in them. Can someone please take a look and suggest a solution to why that's happening.

[image: Design for iPhone SE]

[image]

**Edit** : *Added another image showing view hierarchy.*

[image]

Comment: The problem is not the banner, it’s the banner’s superview.

Comment: 1. Banner's superview is the viewcontroller's view.
2. However, there a 'safe area' below self.view which is not extending to full screen as well. **Edit : Added another image showing view hierarchy.**
How do i solve this problem ?